# Ocultar teclado al lanzar activity con EditText y volver a mostrarlo

Tags: java, android

Usando la línea  `TuEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);` he conseguido ocultar el teclado del EdiText.

No obstante, he puesto `TuEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);` en el OnClickListener del EditText pero sigue sin salir el teclado.

¿Cómo puedo hacer que aparezca al hacer click pero no al lanzar la actividad?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Para evitar que te muestre el teclado al entrar en la actividad no lo tienes que hacer como has puesto, eso tienes que quitarlo.

Para evitar que lo muestre, tienes que hacerlo en el Manifest. Tienes que incluir las siguientes líneas en la actividad en la que quieras ocultar el teclado:

```
android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation"
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
```

Cuando entres a la actividad no te lo mostrará pero cuando selecciones el EditText si.

Para indicar si quieres que solo te puedan poner texto yo lo haría en la definición del layout, en la zona donde defines el Edittext le tienes que poner esto:

```
android:inputType="text"
```

Si quieres poner otro tipo de entrada puedes mirar aquí los que hay: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html

Espero que te sirva.

Answer (score 2):

Tienes varias formas de resolver esto

-En tu **AndroidManifest.xml**: puedes esconder el teclado cuando entras en la actividad mediante la propiedad `windowSoftInputMode` que puedes encontrar en la [documentación](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft). Esta configuración oculta el teclado virtual cuando el usuario abre una nueva Actividad. El teclado se mostrará sólo cuando el usuario hace clic en el EditText.

**Ejemplo:**

```
<activity android:name="com.tu.paquete.Activity"
          android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"  />
```

-Mediante el **InputMethodManager**: si quieres asegurarte de que el método de entrada esté visible/oculto en cualquier parte del ciclo de vida de tu actividad puedes utilizar `InputMethodManager` para mostrarlo, como indica la [documentación](https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/visibility.html#ShowOnDemand).

**Ejemplo:**

```
/**
 * Hides the soft keyboard
 */
public void hideSoftKeyboard() {
    if(getCurrentFocus()!=null) {
        InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
}

/**
 * Shows the soft keyboard
 */
public void showSoftKeyboard(View view) {
    InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    view.requestFocus();
    inputMethodManager.showSoftInput(view, 0);
}
```

Código extraído de la siguiente [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18977227/3683321) de SOEn y de la documentación

Answer (score 1):

La solucuión más sencilla que encontre es agregar el atributo

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

en su layout principal, de la siguiente forma.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:id="@+id/mainLayout" 
android:focusableInTouchMode="true" >
```

Y ahora, cuando se inicia la activity, este layout principal obtendrá el foco de forma predeterminada.